# Why git add all the files even some of them specified in .gitignore

Tags: git

I am pretty to Git.  Currently learning how to ignore file in git.

The command history I used:

```
mkdir testgit
cd testgit
git init
touch .gitignore
echo "./toignore.txt" >>.gitignore
touch toignore.txt
git add .
git status
```

Then, it shows:

```
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   .gitignore
        new file:   toignore.txt
```

I wonder why git still be able to add toignore.txt to stage. And how can I ignore it?

Thanks

Comment: The trailing `./` is the troublemaker here.  remove it and it will work

Comment: @EugeneSh. But why such a behaviour? `./toignore.txt` and `toignore.txt` would point to same file.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks, you save my day! But I still have not figured out the reason, is it because Windows / Linux can not recognize that ./ as directory? If so, how can I specify the directory to ignore?

Comment: In Linux it's the same. I haven't figured the exact reason, this is why I haven't written it as an answer :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. So that means if I am using Linux, that will be fine?

Comment: @EugeneSh. That is not working on linux too. I tried.

Comment: In Linux the trailing dot slash won't work either

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for testing that. So if I want to specify a subfolder and files , I should put "toignore/ignorefile.txt" in .gitignore?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I guess jthill gave an answer, but I just need to figure out what that means, LOL. You guys may understand that.

Comment: @RohitJain I guess jthill gave an answer, but I just need to figure out what that means, LOL. You guys may understand that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to see a sensible argument that git "should" recognize a `./` prefix as meaningless and simply ignore it.  Whether that argument should carry the day is another question, and the fact is git is effectively matching `git ls-files` output directly against the  patterns you give it, not against canonicalized paths of files they might resolve to.   The fix is easy enough: use textually-matching patterns, not ones that rely on local filesystem naming conventions.

See [the `gitignore` docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) for the complete spec,

Comment: Thanks, I do not quite understand textually-matching patterns, could you give me an example how to do that in my case?

Comment: Use /toignore.txt or toignore.txt

Comment: No relative-location patterns, no `./` or `../` or `~/`, no environment variable substitution, only what's allowed for in the docs.